# Optimizing an elastic query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am querying elastic-search 2.1 for data. I have three Doc-type A,B,C in an index.
Doc-type C has reference to both doc-type A and B documents. So, whenever I need to search all the documents in doc-type B that are related to a document in doc-type A.I need to query doc-type C and get all the documents consisting Id of a particular document in doc-type A. Then I need to iterate over those documents and get ids of all documents in Doc-type B. And then fire IdsQuery on doc-type B to get all the documents in B.

My Question is there an optimized way to do this that elastic has provided , irrespective of its version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isnot really clear, if you have a 1->X->X relation ship between A B C you should be childs - parents. I thinck you have to present your data, maybe the modelisation should be reworked.

Comment: C acts as a relationship element between A and B. Also one document in C can have reference to only one other document in A and B. But other document in C can have reference to same document in A and B. Here by reference I mean _id of document in A and B doc-type document are stored in C doc-type document.

Comment: Ok i see. Yours documents are updated ? or are they on readonly? Document's relationship change (if C refers to A1, can C refers to another A later?)

Comment: No, it cannot be changed later.

Comment: Well in this case and you should dernom, so you should include doc A and doc B in doc C, as if doc A is in another doc C. So you wont have to look at for liaison this is ok in nosql. If each time you request a document you need to request over ones or if your documents are not to big this modelisation is ok and is a best practice. The hard part is for update, but if you dont have, this is nice ;)